# apt-get install is failing

Tags: apt, wine

I was following this tutorial to install wine in my machine that is running ubuntu. link: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/12/install-wine-1-8-stable-new-ppa/

After that apt-get install is failing.

This is what I see:

```
...
...
Fetched 4,602 kB in 6s (663 kB/s)
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: 34:ln=01: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

/etc/environment :

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
SUDO_USER=sahith
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I have not changed anything myself in the /etc/environment file.

Comment: did you try `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: that gave me : Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: 34:ln=01: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Comment: or try with `apt-get --configure -a`

Comment: gives : `E: Command line option --configure is not understood in combination with the other options`

Comment: It looks like you have (incorrectly) modified your `/etc/environment` file at some point - you will need to re-edit it and correct the error(s)

Comment: let me add the content of the file

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the second line in the `/etc/environment` file. now, `apt-get install` is working.

my `/etc/environment` now:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
SUDO_USER=sahith
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
_=/usr/bin/env
```